# Clipped not actually clips the Image in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, imageview, xcode11, sdwebimage, clipped

I am trying to clip the image and as we see the UI it looks fine but actually it doesn't clip the image which causes other UI elements to unresponsive.

[image]

Here the code I am using.

```
struct ImageContentView: View {
    var urls:[String] = [
        "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/80im-IBfLODpLDj8d02uEpSVIhqdjen6H6CeFwgRBxeua-Dgw0R3WONFj1Gk8CwB_MufmC9rQ8qHjyWMejwFcJ1PA2s8AAu5WVsmJA=s0-d",
        "https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/530919.jpg"
    ] 
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView{
            VStack{
                Button(action: {
                    
                }, label: {
                    Text("Hello")
                })
                VStack(spacing: 20.0) {
                    ForEach(self.urls, id:\.self) { url in
                        WebImage(url: URL.init(string: url)!)
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: ContentMode.fill)
                            .frame(height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width * 0.5) 
                            .clipped()
                            .cornerRadius(10.0)
                            .shadow(color: Color.red, radius: 10.0, x: 0, y: 0)
                    }
                }.padding()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried ContentShape as well as ClipShape but didn't work.

Comment: Any update on this one? Did you find a solution?

Comment: clipShape and contentShape work for me

Answer (score 7):

Here is fixed part (tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14)

```
VStack(spacing: 20.0) {
    ForEach(self.urls, id:\.self) { url in
        WebImage(url: URL.init(string: url)!)
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: ContentMode.fill)
            .frame(height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width * 0.5)
            .clipped()
            .cornerRadius(10.0)
            .shadow(color: Color.red, radius: 10.0, x: 0, y: 0)
    }.contentShape(Rectangle())   // << here !!
}.padding()
```

*Note: I don't know what is your `WebImage` but with `Image` and local images it was reproduced as well, so fix was tested.*

Comment: WebImage is from SDWebImageSwiftUI library

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I am downloading the image from URL and display it

Comment: Then it is bug in WebImage as well, because above works for Image. You can try also to put .contentShape on VStack.

Comment: Thanks! Simply adding the contentShape Rectangle modifier solved the problem for me.

Comment: It should be noted that it's important that the `.contentShape(Rectangle())` line should be any line after `.clipped()`

Answer (score 4):

I have tried for the above methods but still not working.
Here is another solution for someone who have the same struggle, maybe this can help you :) This line is to disable the tap gesture of the image.

```
Image(uiImage: image)
.resizable()
.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
.frame(width: 100, height: 100)
.contentShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8))
.allowsHitTesting(false) // <- this is the line
```

Answer (score 2):

**iOS 13 and +**

An other solution is combine `compositingGroup` and `clipped`:

That wraps this view in a compositing group and clips.

**Note: Respect this order `compositingGroup` and `clipped`**

```
Image(..)            
.compositingGroup()
.clipped()
```